# Optimized way to store text in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-webview

I am developing an application that has large number of text files, i stored file in asset folder and a webview that has a list of links and while clicking on that links data is displayed. The files that are storerd in asset folder are very big in size, I want to know is there any other way to store the data that can occupy less memory because it is increasing the size of application and creating a lot of extra data.

Comment: How big in file size are we talking about? After all its only text, not images. How are you displaying the text, whats the scenario here? Could server render the wanted text after you click the link on the WebView?

Comment: store them in server? then download it after user install your app

Comment: Store them in server yes, but the server would also render text on the WebView after link is clicked. This all depends on your use case. If this is possible, then you never have to download the text into local files.

Comment: Could you tell the use case of these text files to get a bigger picture of what are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: @Niko what i am doing is i am making a offline app, that has data for my university syllabus, schemes, 5 year back questions, Interview Question and Programs Of C,CPP,JAVA etc....

Comment: Okay, so in that case all data must be bundled in the application. In which format is your text now?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is, Upload all the files to the server, When user first time open your application, Just download all the files and manage their path with your webview links.

This is the same approach used by all the games.

Comment: The problem in this is that what if there is no storage space left and the application is fully depended of these text files.

Comment: How much memory consumed by your textfiles?? If it is really big then I suggest to make API and use API calls to fetch data according to screen.

Comment: @dhuma1981 i am making an offline app, the suggest thing i also thought that when the application first opens download all the data, the application is about 15mb and yet more data will come... and in india user do not much space in there phones...

Comment: @PuneetKushwah if you put all data in your asset folder it will increase the app size and as you said india user do not have much space they will not even install your app, better solution is keep your app size minimum and then let user to download data to access it, if they will find your app worth using, they will definitely make room for your app, the way they make room for their fav. games. :)

Comment: @dhuma1981 yes u r right, means i can conclude by the discussion that i don't store data within the application, i am new to android n i want some guidance how to do that..are you up to help me...

Comment: Happy to be helpful to you :)
All the best for your app.